# How can I build glib at c++ - compile error when build .cpp

Tags: c++, glib

All

When I build cpp using g++ and glib, I meet compile error.
c and gcc version is OK.
I'm building at Ubuntu 10.XX. 
I even built it at windows - c++.

How can I build glib at c++?
Thanks you.

```
#include <glib.h>

int main() {
    g_printf("test");
    return 0;
}

jongwon_kwak@kwak-com:~/worksapce_CXX/TESTGLib/src$ g++ -c -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include TESTGLib.cpp 
TESTGLib.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
TESTGLib.cpp:12:17: error: ‘g_printf’ was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `#include <glib/gprintf.h>`

Comment: Thank you. But I can't understand why it doesn't occur error at gcc & c version.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit this and it will work

```
#include <glib/gprintf.h>
```

Comment: This is not a valid solution. The Glib documentation clearly says that including `<glib/glib.h>` is enough to get all the function/variable declarations.